# Angular Cli build command very slow to commence

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am wondering if there is a log file for this. All of a sudden when I issue any ng command like `ng --version` or `ng build` it takes a long time to actually start, sometimes 10 minutes. Just yesterday, there was no time delay at all.

This is the version I have and am using Angular 5:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.5
Node: 8.9.4
npm 5.6.0
OS: win32 x64
```

I am somewhat puzzled as I don't understand what has changed all of a sudden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs when there is problem in your node libraries. I had same issue i solved it by uninstalling node and i install it again also updated angular core and cli. This solved my problem may be this will solve your issue.

Comment: I have the same issue but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Dois Can you tell me the configuration of your PC

Comment: Hello, I was running my project off a network drive (Windows on all involved computers). The recompile was fast but everytime I ran ng serve I had to wait a really long time. I've sinced moved it to my local disk and it's fast.